# Replacing Radio Buttons with Check Box on License Wizard Page in Inno Setup

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, custom-controls, inno-setup, wizard

Is there any easy way to replace standard 2 radio buttons on License Wizard Page with single (checked/unchecked) Check Box in Inno Setup whithout creating Custom Page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there are no settings to switch between license radio buttons and some license check box (at least just because there's no component for it on the `WizardForm`) you need to create it by your own.

The following code hide the original license radio buttons and creates a check box on the same place at the wizard initialization. This license check box is simulating the radio buttons selections in its `OnClick` event handler to keep their original functionality. Here is the code, which allows you to access the license check box out of the scope of the wizard initialization event. If you don't need to access this check box later on, you can use [`this version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10687494/2) of the post:

```
[code]

var
  LicenseCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;

procedure OnLicenseCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LicenseAccepted: Boolean;
begin
  LicenseAccepted := (Sender as TNewCheckBox).Checked;
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Checked := LicenseAccepted;
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Checked := not LicenseAccepted;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Hide;
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Hide;

  LicenseCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  LicenseCheckBox.Parent := WizardForm.LicensePage;
  LicenseCheckBox.Left := 0;
  LicenseCheckBox.Top := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Top + 
    WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height + 8;
  LicenseCheckBox.Width := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Width;
  LicenseCheckBox.Caption := ' I accept the license agreement';
  LicenseCheckBox.OnClick := @OnLicenseCheckBoxClick;
end;
```

Comment: Just a small update, there's no need to use variable for instantiating that check box...

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow, but seems to be OK. The best part is keeping CODE clear when there are many functions and procedures to concatenate.

Comment: Exactly! The variable with check box instance was useless here because it was not used out of scope of the `InitializeWizard`. And even local variable is not needed, the `with` statement is enough for this case. The check box itself will be destroyed when its owner is destroyed (the `WizardForm`), but even this ownership is not important because the whole form is destroyed after you finish the wizard and that's the time when you give the whole memory used by the setup back to the system.

Comment: OK, I have checked and this new solution is OK, but previous one was giving you more power over Enabling, Disabling, Hiding CheckBox - so combining e.g. with License Scroll procedure was easier. I think that both solutions should be posted as "nice and quick" and "more advanced". In fact the fist one was better for me.

Comment: Fixed, I forgot about your previous intention with license memo :-)