# How to enable or disable the Next button by check box?

Tags: inno-setup

I want the Next button event like this:

> If the user checks the checkbox (not radio button), next button will
>   be enabled; otherwise it will be disabled.

My code:

```
if CheckBox.Checked then
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True
else
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
```

But these codes require refreshing current page (for example, back to previous page and again return to current page); otherwise in spite of the fact that if the user checks the checkbox, next button won't be enabled.

How to do this without refreshing page like license agreement radio buttons (dynamic next button)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't make any sense of this feature, but from what I understand, you are looking for a way to handle the check box state change event. That's what the check box `OnClick` event is for. For example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := TNewCheckBox(Sender).Checked;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
begin
  CheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  CheckBox.Parent := WizardForm;
  CheckBox.Top := WizardForm.BackButton.Top;
  CheckBox.Left := 8;
  CheckBox.Checked := True;
  CheckBox.Caption := 'Can I continue?';
  CheckBox.OnClick := @CheckBoxClick;
end;
```

Comment: If this question is specifically about replacing license radio buttons with a check box, then it's been asked in [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10687135/960757).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to implement a License page.

Inno already has support for this; simply set the [`LicenseFile` setting](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_licensefile.htm) to the name of a local txt or rtf file containing the license text that you want to display.

Inno will then compile this text into the installer and will display a license page with Yes/No radio buttons, and only allow the user to continue the installation once they have selected the Yes option.

Comment: *...a license page with Yes/No radio buttons*, yes, radio buttons. But this question is specifically about check box. OP seems to be aware of the license file feature in Inno Setup.

Comment: Usually that sort of thing comes from misguided specifications, and usually the client doesn't really care if they're checkboxes or radiobuttons.